# How to delete indent from div element? HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I create navigation block, but it's look like there is some margin exist, ca someone give advice for that issue?

[image: Looks like this]
Below I try delete that by setting padding, margin = 0px;

```
div.topnav
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is way too generic, I would do something similar but only over body element, instead wildcard "*"

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```